# pygameでメイン処理と動画読み込み処理を並行して行いたい

Tags: python, python3, pygame

やりたいこととしては「メイン処理を行いながら、動画の読み込みをサイズ上限を超えないように行う」という処理を行いたいです。

試したことは以下の通りです。

- Python標準の「futures.ThreadPoolExecutor」を使ってみたところFPSが極端に落ちてしまう
  （動画読み込み処理が完了するとFPSが元に戻るので、スレッドだとメイン処理と読み込み処理が交互に動いてると見て間違いなさそうです）
- Python標準の「futures.ProcessPoolExecutor」を使うとグローバル変数がメイン処理と読み込み処理で共有できない

この場合、一番効率的な並行処理はどういったものがあるのか、ご助力願いたいです。

以下、サンプルソースを記載します。

```
## スレッドのテスト
import cv2
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
from concurrent import futures
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import traceback

MOVIE_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../img/movie")

test_mp4 = cv2.VideoCapture(MOVIE_PATH+"/test.mp4")
mp4_fps = test_mp4.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
frame_list = []
is_game_end = False

def mp4_reset():
    global test_mp4, frame_list
    test_mp4.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0)
    frame_list = []

def mp4_read():
    global test_mp4, frame_list, is_game_end
    while(1):
        if is_game_end:
            break
        if sys.getsizeof(frame_list) > 1000:
            continue
        ret, frame = test_mp4.read()
        if ret:
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            frame = np.rot90(frame)
            frame = np.flipud(frame)
            frame_list.append(frame)
        print(sys.getsizeof(frame_list))
    print("mp4_read end")


def main():
    global frame_list, is_game_end
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280,720))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 50)
    try :
        while(1):
            screen.fill((100,100,100))

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    is_game_end = True
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == K_SPACE:
                        mp4_reset()
            
            if len(frame_list) > 0:
                frame = frame_list.pop(0)
                frame = pygame.surfarray.make_surface(frame)
                screen.blit(frame, (0,0))
            
            text = font.render(f"frame_size:{len(frame_list)}, fps:{clock.get_fps()}", True, (255,255,255))
            screen.blit(text, (0,0))

            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(60)
    except Exception as e:
        is_game_end = True
        print(e)
        print(traceback.format_exc())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    future_list = []
    ## ▼マルチプロセスで動かそうとしたもの
    with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
        future_list.append(executor.submit(mp4_read))
        future_list.append(executor.submit(main))
        _ = futures.as_completed(fs=future_list)
    ## ▼スレッドを使用した時のコード
    # with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    #     future_list.append(executor.submit(mp4_read))
    #     future_list.append(executor.submit(main))
    #     _ = futures.as_completed(fs=future_list)
    print("end")
```

環境は以下の通りです

- python : 3.9.7
- opencv-python : 4.5.4.60
- numpy : 1.21.4
- pygame : 2.1.0

▼PCスペック（参考）

- OS : Windows10 pro
- CPU : Ryzen 9 5950X
- RAM : 64GB
- GPU : GTX 1050ti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決できたかもしれないので共有します

▼参考
https://eqseqs.hatenablog.com/entry/2020/09/16/100000

まず上記の記事を参考にアレンジしてビデオ読み込みスレッド用のクラスを作ります

▼ video.py

```
import threading
import queue
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

MOVIE_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../img/movie")

class ThreadingVideoCapture:
    def __init__(self, src, max_queue_size=256):
        self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(MOVIE_PATH+"/"+src)
        self.q = queue.Queue(maxsize=max_queue_size)
        self.stopped = False
        print("video init")

    def start(self):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.update, daemon=True)
        thread.start()
        return self

    def update(self):
        while True:

            if self.stopped:
                return

            if not self.q.full():

                ok, frame = self.video.read()

                if not ok:
                    self.stop()
                    return
                
                frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                frame = np.rot90(frame)
                frame = np.flipud(frame)
                self.q.put((ok, frame))
            else:
                time.sleep(1)

    def read(self):
        return self.q.get() if not self.q.empty() else None

    def stop(self):
        self.stopped = True

    def release(self):
        self.stopped = True
        self.video.release()

    def isOpened(self):
        return self.video.isOpened()

    def get(self, i):
        return self.video.get(i)

    def q_size(self):
        return self.q.qsize()
```

このクラスを活用してpygameに描画します

▼ main.py

```
## スレッドのテスト
import cv2
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from common import *
import traceback

import video

test_mp4 = video.ThreadingVideoCapture("test.mp4",100)
if not test_mp4.isOpened():
    raise Exception
mp4_fps = test_mp4.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
test_mp4.start()
is_game_end = False

def mp4_reset():
    global test_mp4
    test_mp4.release()
    test_mp4 = video.ThreadingVideoCapture("test.mp4",100)
    test_mp4.start()

def main():
    global test_mp4, is_game_end
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_W,SCREEN_H))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 50)
    try :
        while(not is_game_end):
            screen.fill((100,100,100))

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    is_game_end = True
                    pygame.quit()
                elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == K_SPACE:
                        mp4_reset()
            
            if is_game_end :
                break            
            
            read_data = test_mp4.read()
            if read_data != None and read_data[0]:
                frame = pygame.surfarray.make_surface(read_data[1])
                screen.blit(frame, (0,0))
            
            text = font.render(f"frame_size:{test_mp4.q_size()}, fps:{clock.get_fps()}", True, COLOR_WHITE)
            screen.blit(text, (0,0))

            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(60)
    except Exception as e:
        is_game_end = True
        print(e)
        print(traceback.format_exc())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    print("end")
```

特に追加で外部ライブラリも必要なく要件を満たせました
他にいい方法があれば回答お待ちしています